# Hibernate: Enforcing SQL uniqueness without constraints

Tags: sql, hibernate, constraints, unique-constraint

I'm developing an application using Hibernate. One of the fields I insert must be unique in a table. The problem here is that the field is not the primary key and the underlying database does not support "UNIQUE" constraints. So I have to enforce this in my application code.

This pseudocode is what I have so far:

```
void insert(Data data) {

  beginTransaction();

  boolean exists = existsRecordWithName(data.name);

  // Line 7

  if (exists == false) {
    insertRecord(data);
  } else {
    display("Name already exists in database!");
  }

  commit();
}
```

But if two different processes where to insert data at the same time, and the two reached line number 7, they would think there is no other record at the database with the same name and they both would insert it -> the result is a duplicate.

So how could I enforce uniqueness this way? If I were using pure SQL I would try to lock the table but I'm looking for a higher level solution involving Hibernate standard features, so it would continue working if I someday change the backend.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can't *enforce* unique constraints using application code. Constraints, strictly speaking, apply to all users. What you do in application code only applies to users who happen to use that application code. Constraints in application code don't apply, for example, to DBAs or developers that use a command-line tool or GUI utility to access the database.

Having said that, a SQL DBMS will usually support locks and transactions. If you can't enforce uniqueness by declaring a column unique, your next best bet is to explicitly lock the table and maybe wrap your changes in a serializable transaction.  I think locking the table should be enough, but I'm not going to make bets on a system that doesn't support unique constraints.

What dbms doesn't support unique constraints?  I'm pretty sure I've *never* seen such a thing, and I started working with databases almost 30 years ago.

Comment: I tried to wrap my code inside a serializable transaction but nothing changed. To be sure, I made a little test with PostgreSQL and the result was the same... The query I use to check if a row exists is a simple `select count(*)` so I think serializable behavior here is the same as read-commited. Ah, the dbms I'm using is a rare propietary thing imposed by the final user ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do locking using hibernate too (LockMode) provided your database supports it, but locking with inserts is tricky business (how do you lock something that does not yet exist). btw what happens if you do a unique="true" for this entity? does hibernate throw an error saying it can not, or does it allow duplicates? I am assuming you have correctly implemented equals and hashcode methods.

In your code outline above, you could intern() the name and do a synchronized block around the code on the name - that may work.

Comment: I'm getting duplicates after setting uniqueConstraints in hibernate mapping (using annotations). Your solution of using a synchronized block could make the trick, but I'll leave it to the last resort ;-)

Comment: actually, even that would work only on a single JVM, if you have a clustered setup, you can still have a problem.